# Can you remove response filters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, filtering, response

I have an HttpModule where I lookup the content type and then apply some filters to the response. There are some instances where I don't want to apply one of these filters but that isn't determined until the page_load event later on. Is there any way to remove a filter??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...I think the answer is, No...

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Response.Filter = null;
```

It removes all filters, not just one, but worked for me.